# Why is NProbability far off with standard options for DirichletDistribution?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, probability-or-statistics

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3711872] was created.

EDIT:  As of Version 11.1.0 the issue is resolved.

---

### Background

*Bayesian Data Analysis, 3rd ed., 2013* by Gelman et al. on page 69 f. has a nice and simple example for using Bayesian inference with a multinomial distribution which has the Dirichlet distribution as its conjugate prior distribution (here the 51st presidential elections in the US). So I felt like checking it quickly.

### The Setting

We do find that the posterior distribution for the share of voters supporting Mr. Bush ($x_1$), Mr. Dukakis ($x2$) and what else have you ($x3$) after doing a survey of 1447 adults (observing the proportions $(y1,y2,y3)$) using a noninformative prior distribution (e.g. $Dir(1,1,1)$ ) is given by a *Dirichlet distribution*:

$
 {x1, x2, x3| {y1,y2,y3}} \sim Dir( 728, 584, 138 )
$

In *Mathematica* this can be encoded as:

```
posteriorDistr = DirichletDistribution[ { 728, 584, 138 }]
```

### Numerical Issues

We can now do posterior inference about the probability, that Mr. Bush will get more votes than Mr. Dukakis using [`Probability`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html):

```
N @ Probability[ x1 > x2, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] posteriorDistr ]
```

> 0.999966

Which is the correct result (Mr. Bush is set to become the 41st POTUS). But note what we get, if we use [`NProbability`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NProbability.html) which is much faster than `Probability`:

```
NProbability[ x1 > x2, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] posteriorDistr ]
```

> 0.562617

There is no warning and the result is far off the mark.

**Why is `NProbability`so bad in choosing an appropriate method in this (still rather simple) case?**

(Note, that we do get the correct result, if we give the option `Method -> "MonteCarlo"` for example.)

### EDIT

As of Version 11.1.0 the issue is resolved:

```
NProbability[x1 > x2, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] posteriorDistr]
```

> 0.999964

`NProbability` will now also pass on a warning that comes up in `NIntegrate` which tells us that the numerical integration is converging too slowly.

Comment: Just use something like `Method -> {"NIntegrate", {MinRecursion -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 5}}` in `NProbability`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's more the fault of `NIntegrate` than `NProbability`.
Compare

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[x1 > x2] PDF[DirichletDistribution[{728, 584, 138}], {x1, x2}], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}]
```

with

```
N@Integrate[
 Boole[x1 > x2] PDF[DirichletDistribution[{728, 584, 138}], {x1, x2}], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}]
```

One can use

```
NProbability[x1 > x2, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] posteriorDistr, Method -> "Trace"]
```

to reveal that `NIntegrate` is used and the integrand isn't numerically friendly.

Comment: Sure thing, but calling NProbability and listening to WRI marketing, you would expect, that there is more internal detection and at least some kind of warning?

Comment: @gwr Anyhow, you should send them a bug report.

Comment: @Karsten7. +1 but `NProbability` potentially could analyse the problem and select appropriate options to pass to `NIntegrate`.  It has much more context to work with than `NIntegrate`